# What's the order of publication of classic Spycraft products?

Tags: history-of-gaming, publishing, spycraft

While [classic *Spycraft*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spycraft#Classic_Spycraft_2) didn't suffer the same sort of abundant rules replacement that plagued, for example, *Dungeons & Dragons 3.5*, enough occurs that it bothers me that the books are silent on their publication months and, sometimes, years. The first edition *Spycraft* primary bibliography includes the texts in the following list. This list excludes treeware magazine articles and electronic material.

If the year below is inaccurate, in what year was the product actually published? Further, during what month was each product published?

## 2002

- *Spycraft Espionage Handbook*
- *Game Control Screen and Agent Record Sheets*
- *Shadowforce Archer*
- *Modern Arms Guide*
- *Gentlemen’s Agreement*
- *Archer Foundation*
- *Soldier/Wheelman Class Guide*
- *Hand of Glory*

## 2003

- *Pan-Asian Collective*
- *Fixer/Pointman Class Guide*
- *Faceman/Snoop Class Guide*
- *European Commonwealth*
- *African Alliance*
- *The Shop*
- *The 1960s*
- *Most Wanted*<sup>1</sup>
- *Stargate SG–1 Roleplaying Game*<sup>2</sup>
- *Fantastic Frontiers*<sup>2</sup>

## 2004

- *Agency*
- *Mastermind*
- *U. S. Militaries*
- *World Militaries*
- *Dark Inheritance*<sup>1</sup>
- *First Steps*<sup>2</sup>
- *Friends and Foes*<sup>2</sup>
- *Living Gods*<sup>2</sup>
- *Strike Force 7*<sup>1</sup>

## 2005

- *Battlegrounds*

---

<sup>**1**</sup> This product isn't an official classic *Spycraft* product but bears the Powered by *Spycraft* seal. Further, except for *Strike Force 7*, the product saw *Spycraft* developers consult on the product.
<sup>**2**</sup> While *Stargate SG–1 Role-playing Game* products aren't *Spycraft* products, the line is classic *Spycraft* compatible, and the line's products saw *Spycraft* developers works on those products.

---

***Note:*** [Crafty Games](https://www.crafty-games.com/) now publishes classic Spycraft. *The Crafty Games forums hosts [this identical question](https://www.crafty-games.com/forum/index.php?topic=8798.0) that has been met so far with relative silence.*

Comment: @HeyICanChan Does the bibliography include ISBNs for the books?

Comment: @AVeryLargeBear All of those texts *have* ISBNs, but it's my homemade bibliography so I'd have to enter ISBNs by hand. An intrepid researcher could find those texts' ISBNs on, like, Amazon, though. (To be clear, I don't know how to get a publication date from just an ISBN.)

Comment: You can't get publication date from the ISBN unless that is how you find the book. The way they work is (for 10 digit - 2007 and earlier) First number - region and language of publication, second string - publisher information, third string - title information, last number - check code(from unknown math calc), in the 13 digit(after 2007) the beginning three numbers are **supposed** to be a publication date identifier but since there are only two number used for that (978 or 979) they are pretty useless. Unfortunately for many of these numbers Amazon only lists the year of publication.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After trawling through numerous websites as well as hitting up the Wayback Machine more than once I found the information you were looking for.  This is the best/most accurate information I can find short of buying the books and looking them up in the books themselves.  Most of this information by the way came from the Wayback Machine archived pages of the original publisher AEG. Hope this helps you.

2002

- *Spycraft Espionage Handbook* – March 2002
- *Game Control Screen and Agent Record Sheets* – March 2002
- *Shadowforce Archer* – April 2002
- *Modern Arms Guide* – June 2002
- *Gentlemen’s Agreement* – December 2002
- *Archer Foundation* – July 2002
- *Soldier/Wheelman Class Guide* – September 2002
- *Hand of Glory* – October 2002

2003

- *Pan-Asian Collective* – April 2003
- *Fixer/Pointman Class Guide* – March 2003
- *Faceman/Snoop Class Guide* – July 2003
- *European Commonwealth* – May 2003
- *African Alliance* – September 2003
- *The Shop* – December 2003
- *The 1960s* – October 2003
- *Most Wanted* – Published under license by Paradigm Concepts – no date beyond year found
- *Stargate SG–1 Roleplaying Game* – July 2003
- *Fantastic Frontiers* – December 2003

2004

- *Agency* – March 2004
- *Mastermind* – June 2004
- *U. S. Militaries* – September 2004
- *World Militaries* – November 2004
- *Dark Inheritance* – October 2004
- *First Steps* – August 2004
- *Friends and Foes* – June 2004
- *Living Gods* – February 2004
- *Strike Force 7* – December 2004

2005

- *Battlegrounds* – February 2005

Comment: Wow. Outstanding. Thank you! I hadn't expected *that* method—that is, *waybacking* through the AEG site—, but far be it from me to complain! And, seriously, were it as simple as buying the books and looking in them, I'd totally do that—I own all these books, but that information is simply absent. So, thank you, and I'm *really* glad you didn't go the extra *extra* mile and buy the books only to be disappointed! (That is, in them not have publication months—they're good books!)

Comment: Looking at the descriptions they are now on my 'if I can afford' list because they do look interesting.  As far as the Wayback Machine?  I use it a lot, you'd be surprised at some of the stuff that is archived.

Comment: @doppelgreener What inspired the change to the *Battlegrounds* publication date?

Comment: @HeyICanChan It was listed in the section headed 2005, but was attributed to December 2004, so I went and checked its release date.